# shortcut to bring hidden Chrome window to front on Mac?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, window-manager

On Mac OS 10.10, I have two google chrome windows stacked on top of each other.  How can I bring the window that is hidden behind to the front?  From the "Window" menu, I can select the window that I want, but I would like to be able to cycle through the windows with a keyboard shortcut.

Cmd-tab will let me cycle through open applications, but it groups all the chrome windows together, so I can't reveal the covered window.

Control-tab will cycle through the tabs of the focused chrome window, but this is not what I want.

Any ideas how I can reveal the hidden chrome window?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>~</kbd>  (tilde, or even ` as shift appears to be optional) will cycle all windows of the frontmost app.
 <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>F4</kbd>  will cycle through all open windows in that Space, irrespective of app.

Comment: This worked, but then I minimized or something, and then it would only show one screen. Even though another window was playing music, there was no way to get to it, till I right-click > Options > show all windows. Who thought that would be a good idea, or is that just apple being anti-competative?

Comment: @TravisHeeter - Apple has had Spaces for 15 years. The idea of that was to reduce the need to minimise at all. [the introduction of Fullscreen, which appeals to laptop owners with small screens, kind of put paid to the great work done in Spaces & the two don't work well together, unfortunately] There's a fuller work-through on how the window cycling process works here - https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/193937/85275 and a couple of Spaces guides at https://superuser.com/a/1187552/347380 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179403/85275

Comment: thanks for the references. I will gladly learn how to wield the mac better.

Comment: I'm using Chrome version 111.0.5563.64 with macOS Catalina 10.15.27, I have 2 active Chrome windows open (and another 4 that refuse to appear in the Window menu, which is why I ended up at this question) and 2 other Mac windows open, **but [Cmd + `] does nothing**, ditto adding Shift. Same with Ctrl+F4. So maybe this answer doesn't apply to Catalina or later.

Comment: @ChappoHasn'tForgottenMonica - there's a far more comprehensive version of this QA at https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/193937/85275 which includes all sorts of caveats.

Answer (score 3):

Click and hold the mouse over the Chrome icon in the Dock. Then go to <kbd>Options</kbd> and under <kbd>Assign To</kbd>, select <kbd>Desktop on Display 1</kbd>. For me, it was set to <kbd>None</kbd>.

Screenshot of how to do it:

[image]

Comment: This isn't the solution, as I have the same problem as the OP but my Chrome is already assigned to "Desktop on Display 1". Clicking & holding the Chrome icon does provide the "Show All Windows" option (see the screenshot) allowing you to select the Chrome window even if it's hidden – which resolves the problem I was having, so thanks for leading me to the Dock (lol)! – but this requires even more clicks than selecting the other Chrome window from the Window menu.