# How do I maximize windows under macOS where no "zoom" option is available?

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, macos-highsierra

I am a Linux user and new to macOS. I installed some programs such as `google-chrome` and `macvim` from `brew`. After launching both of them, I can not make the window maximize. Normally, for the built-in Terminal and some other apps, I can use `Zoom` to make them maximize, but not for these two apps. I can `Ctrl+command+F` to fullscreen them, but that is not what I want – I just want to maximize them.

Is such a simple maximize action not supported under macOS?

Comment: Please spend some time to learn how to use your new machine, rather than whine because it doesn't do the same as your old one. https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204216

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I did google, I can not find an answer, that's why I asked this question. I did learn and spent times. I am NOT just asking questions without doing my work. All I found online is Zoom does not maximize and macos determines whether it should maximize or not. BUT that is NOT what I want. I just want to maximize. That's all. I don't care about whether it should or not. I just want to maximize. Thanks.

Comment: Then read the link I posted... or Google ['macOS maximise window'](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=macos+maximise+window&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) where the same page is the first hit.

Comment: @Tetsujin I just read the link and the section `Close & resize windows`. It still doesn't solve my question. google-chrome and mvim are still not able to maximize. What am I missing? thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean "fill the whole screen without making it fullscreen"... that's not Maximise. As screens got larger & with higher definition several [many] years ago, the old definition of 'maximise' was changed. Maximise is now 'fills top to bottom, half the screen width [or less for such as finder windows]. If you want the old, windows-type 'take up the whole damn screen' behaviour, you'll have to drag the window border.

Comment: @Tetsujin maybe you misunderstand my question. I am not talking about zoom. I am talking about maximize. Maximize will make the app's window occupy all the screen. I know how to zoom and I know I can hold option key and click green button. But they are not maximize. They are just fake maximize. I want a true maximize. thanks a lot.

Comment: @Tetsujin sorry, I posted the last comment at the same time you posted. Yeah, that is what I want and that is not `windows-type`, that is `Linux-type` from my point of view. I hope someone in superuser can tell me how to hack macos to make this possible. thanks a lot.

Comment: There's a list of potential methods/apps at https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/115895/85275 Also, not at all what you asked for, but try this for a working method, long term, save a whole lot of messing around with alt/tab... https://superuser.com/q/1187532/347380

Comment: @Tetsujin thank you very much for the two links. ^_^

Comment: Welcome - & apologies for getting snippy, sometimes it's a bit rough when you think someone's picking holes in an OS you've been using variants of for 30 years ;-))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a simple keyboard shortcut to maximize the window to fit the *full* screen, without actually going fullscreen, you can install [Spectacle](https://www.spectacleapp.com/) and set up the shortcut for “Fullscreen” (I know the naming is misleading here):

[image]

For example, I've set up <kbd>⌃⌥⌘F</kbd>.

If you're used to Linux' and Windows' tiling window management shortcuts, this app will also provide you with similar functionality.

Comment: That’s fullscreen.  I believe the OP wants to grow the window in both directions to fill the available space on screen, without actually entering fullscreen mode.

Comment: @CJK that is actually NOT fullscreen. It's maximize (what I expect). This app is very useful and actually I have installed it based on Tetsujin's comments before this answer's post.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.