# Equivalent shortcut to windows + number fromWindows 10 in macOS?

Tags: windows-10, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome, macos-mojave

One of my favorite keyboard shortcuts in Windows (and Gnome in linux) is <kbd>windows key</kbd>+<kbd>number</kbd> which opens the program that is that position in the task bar (and repeated presses change between opened windows in case there is more than one).

At work I’ve been assigned a MacBook Pro with mac OS Mojave and so far apart from the keyboard being quite different and mistyping the big thing that I haven’t been able to find a replacement is that shortcut.

Is there a default shortcut that can do that or I am just out of luck and have to switch with <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> or using the mouse?

Comment: You're going to need a slight paradigm shift, but it's possible to do an equivalent, with even higher precision as the places never move once set up.. The trick is to set up Spaces - different desktops, to which you then assign an app or related group of apps. You can then key-command between them & each time it will bring the desired app frontmost, as well as slide to the Space it occupies. If that sounds like something you'd like to try, I can drop details into an answer.

Comment: @Tetsujin it would at least be a nice workaround, please tell us these details :)

Comment: @Samuel -  See https://superuser.com/a/1187552/347380 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179403/85275

Answer (score 1):

Just found an app called [Snap](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/snap/id418073146) in Mac App Store that does just that

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).