# Is it possible to rename Spaces in macOS Catalina?

Tags: macos, macos-catalina

Just wondering if there's a way to rename a Space in Mission Control?
Found [this discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250775564) on Apple Community, supporting the idea it's just not possible.
Seems that apart for an app in full screen, whose name is reused for the corresponding Space, all other Spaces just get an incremented name like Desktop1, Desktop2 and so on.
Thanks.

Comment: No, it's not possible. Best you can do is set up a bunch of Spaces, assign specific apps to them, then remember the numbers. See https://superuser.com/a/1187552/347380 for more detail.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin, very detailed and useful explanation indeed. At least I won't spend more time searching for this feature.