# cmd-tab to all active windows

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors

I've recently started using my iPad as a second screen with Sidecar.

This is a great feature, I travel a lot and having a second, smaller screen is incredibly handy.  Usually I end up putting secondary windows like my browser's development tools on it.

This is almost 100% what I want, except when cmd-tabbing between applications where I have one window on each monitor, where both are full-screened.  In this case only one window will be brought to front or, more likely, the secondary window will still be active and cmd-tabbing does nothing at all.

**What I would really like is when I switch applications, for full-screened windows of that app on any and all monitors to be brought to the front.**

Comment: As soon as you start using fullscreen with multiple monitors, you lose control. It's just not a robust-enough structure unfortunately.

Comment: @Tetsujin that's unfortunate.  I strongly prefer it to stacking all of my windows up on one desktop :(

Comment: You can use Spaces - many as you like. I have 7 across 2 monitors, 14 "screens" in effect, but I move them in pairs rather than independently. As none are fullscreen, they have each a number & a key command, so I usually flip to my next wanted app [or collection of apps sharing a large 2x27" space] by number rather than cmd/tab. I did a comprehensive answer on setup & usage a couple of years ago. See https://superuser.com/a/1187552/347380 & see if it might be of any use to you. I don't know how/if Sidecar behaves in exactly the same way as regular displays & have no means to test it.

Comment: @Tetsujin this is quite impressive, but it might just be that you have a better brain for organization than I do - I'm pretty simple in my schemes and one of the things I like about full-screen is it doesn't let me get careless and start stacking and forgetting about windows.

Comment: I might be occasionally accused of tendencies towards OCD & Asperger's [guilty on both counts, though extremely mildly] but I found it takes very little time to prepare yourself that, eg, browsing & general Finder-type stuff goes on 1, my DAW on 3, spreading over both screens completely, Mail on 4 [all on its own, just because it ended up that way] Photoshop-type stuff on 5, 6 & 7 [because they all need a lot of space] Then all you have to do is remember the number. Doesn't take long.