# Dedicated hotkey for chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, mac, hotkeys

I am using Mac OS. I am wondering if there is a way to set a hotkey to always bring the Chrome application to the front? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. I used to use Quicksilver for this, but that’s complicated and doesn’t seem to work on M1 Macs (or maybe it’s Big Sur, can’t tell). So, I created a “service” in Automator that launches Chrome (web search for creating a service!), then set a keyboard shortcut for the service in the Keyboard pref pane.

Comment: Or you could just put it on a known numbered Space & call up that Space by key command. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179403/85275 and https://superuser.com/a/1187552/347380 for some examples.

Comment: I tried to set this up with Karabiner but it seems complicated. I did not know about Spaces but that seems like a good idea. @Tetsujin can you make an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments - This is more of a frame challenge than an answer to the question as asked.

Rather than trying to set up a key to bring one app to the front, if you set up each app in its own Space (Desktop - Apple uses the two terms interchangeably) then you can easily use the built-in key commends to bring that Space & therefore that app to the front.

Rather than reiterate the exact procedures, see
[Ask Different - What is an efficient way for developers / power users to use OSX window management and Spaces on a single screen?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179376/what-is-an-efficient-way-for-developers-power-users-to-use-osx-window-manageme) and
[MacOS Sierra - Full screen/multi desktop WITH menu bar](https://superuser.com/questions/1187532/macos-sierra-full-screen-multi-desktop-with-menu-bar) for various use-cases.