# MacOS - How to switch between windows, irrespective of the app?

Tags: windows, macos, keyboard-shortcuts, alt-tab

I wish to switch between windows the way I used to do it on MicroSoft Windows.

On Windows 10 for instance, the OS doesn't care what app my screen is currently focused on. If I have two Firefox windows, and two Webstorm windows opened. I'll be able to switch like this Firefox 1 - Webstorm 1 - Firefox 2 - Webstorm 2, with `Alt + Tab`.

On MacOS, I am forced to use two different shortcuts: `Cmd + Tab` for switching between *apps*. And `Cmd + `` for switching between opened windows of that app.

Do you have any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally came across an app that do just that as expected: https://alt-tab-macos.netlify.app

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. There's no built-in way to do this, but this app works great.

Answer (score 1):

Windows considers every Window to be a separate application instance. macOS doesn't, merely different views into the same instance. That essential paradigm difference is why you need two commands.

There is a workaround, but it's very arbitrary…  You can use  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>F4</kbd>  to cycle between all windows - but it really is **all** windows, no matter what or where they are.

See [Ask Different - Shortcut for toggling between different windows of same app?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193937/shortcut-for-toggling-between-different-windows-of-same-app/193938#193938) for some other usage tips.

So long as you're not using Fullscreen, then I'd investigate using Spaces instead - see https://superuser.com/a/1187552/347380 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179403/85275

Answer (score 0):

On `MacOS Ventura 13.6` and later this should work:

To switch windows of the same app (for example 2 or 3 Firefox windows, or multiple Terminal windows): press `command-backtick` with the `backtick` being the key to the left of the `1` key.  This is really nice because alt-tab switches apps completely, while `command-backtick` just switches windows within the same app.  If you press it when an app only has one window, nothing happens (which is good). Press `shift-command-backtick` to go in reverse order.

Side note: In a web browser, to change tabs, press `ctrl-tab` to go to the right tab and `shift-ctrl-tab` to go to the left tab. You can cycle through tabs very quickly this way.