# How to switch to another window in macOS?

Tags: windows, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

Sometimes I have two windows open in macOS. But one question, how to switch to another window in macOS? Is there any keyboard shortcut to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I switch to another window in macOS?

<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>: Switch to the next most recently used app among your open apps.

Source: [Mac keyboard shortcuts - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236)

> You can use <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to cycle between all windows

Source: [MacOS - How to switch between windows, irrespective of the app?](https://superuser.com/a/1646889/337631), answer by [Tetsujin](https://superuser.com/users/347380/tetsujin)

See Also: [macos - Shortcut for toggling between different windows of same app? - Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193937/shortcut-for-toggling-between-different-windows-of-same-app)

Comment: For the same app, there's also - https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/193937/85275 - on Ask Different.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thx, added to answer