# Quickly jump to a specific application in Mac OS

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, macbook, automator

My most used applications are `iterm` and `Google-Chrome`. I usually have several other applications open in the background.

Is there a way to create keyboard shortcuts to move focus to my most used applications, namely `iterm` and `google-chrome`?

I think `i3` lets you do this on Linux. I have tried several applications on Mac OS, but I was not able to do this using any of them. I even tried the automator app to create application launch services for `iterm` and `google-chrome`, and assigned keyboard shortcuts for those services from System Preferences, but that worked inconsistently and was slow. When I was inside google-chrome, pressing the keyboard shortcut to move focus to 'iterm' did not work. Not sure why.

I am just looking for some way to set up keyboard shortcuts that will let me quickly move focus to my most used applications.

Comment: Have you considered just using Spaces with key commands rather than trying to persuade Cmd/Tab to do it? See https://superuser.com/a/1187552/347380 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179403/85275 for some use-cases.

Comment: @Tetsujin Is there a way to move between spaces quickly? The animation when moving between spaces makes it slow.

Comment: use key commands* directly to the space number, don't use swipe or any 'next space' shortcut- they are at least half the speed.  [& definitely don't use fullscreen apps as they cannot be numbered… plus a million other reasons I hate them ;) *tested, you can start typing immediately by this method, by the slow method you have to wait for the anim to finish

Comment: @Tetsujin what do you mean by 'use key commands'?

Comment: Read the links I provided.

Comment: @Tetsujin awesome... exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: I’m very happy with http://www.apptivateapp.com/, which is more flexible for me, I don’t need to dedicate Spaces to apps.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Tetsujin, this is how I have set it up.

See this link for general usage of mission control -  [superuser.com/a/1187552/347380](http://%20superuser.com/a/1187552/347380)

Launch Mission Control, and assign `iterm` to space1 and `google-chrome` to space2. Disable automatic reshuffling of spaces from `System Preferences -> Mission Control`. I also check `reduce motion` under `System Preferences -> Accessibility -> Display`

Then I enable the keyboard shortcuts for spaces from `System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Mission Control`. I reassigned the keyboard shortcuts to be friendlier, eg. `Ctrl-Alt-j` and `Ctrl-Alt-k` for spaces 1 and 2.

And lastly, I launched terminal and did the following to speed up animation.

`defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSAutomaticWindowAnimationsEnabled -bool NO`

Thus, with a quick key-combination, I can switch to my most used applications very fast.