# How to make CMD+TAB activate the last active window of the selected application?

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors

There are many wrong answers here and other places on Google. Here is the scenerio:

1. Use more than 1 window and more than 1 desktop.
2. Have browser open on monitor A. This you never want to activate, you are just reading from it
3. Have a second window of the same browser open on monitor B. This you want to tab to.
4. Have a fullscreen app like a terminal also on monitor B.
5. Activate the second browser window on monitor B
6. Tab to terminal
7. **TRY TO TAB BACK TO BROWSER and end up with browser on monitor A as active** and monitor B still showing the terminal.
8. At this point people suggest using CMD+~ to switch focused window. This does not work when the window I want is "hidden in an inactive desktop".

Desired effect:

CMD+TAB brings be back to the last active window of the selected application in app switcher. Meaning I could tab between the two applications/desktops on monitor B without messing with monitor A or browser window there.

How can I make it so that cmd+tab works like this? Is there a setting I am unaware of or is there maybe a tool that works like this instead?

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: How can I achieve my desired effect? Either through a config or third party tool to make mac behave the way I expect/desire it to.

Comment: Why not just use the Spaces key commands instead? Basically, you're fighting a paradigm [one that Jobs started, & Cook forgot about, so you now have two broken structures] - Spaces was never designed to work with an app spread over more than one Space & fullscreen broke the existing perfectly good Spaces implementation. So, you're stuck. Cmd/Tab is always going to go back to a seemingly randomly-chosen 'favourite' window… which is also broken by having an app on multiple Spaces]

Comment: Which spaces command? If I type "chrome" in cmd+space I still get sent to the wrong widow.

Comment: Spaces itself is key-commandable. See System Prefs>Keyboard>Shortcuts>Mission Control. Also see https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/193937/85275 for a seriously fiddly way to do this, or https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179376/what-is-an-efficient-way-for-developers-power-users-to-use-osx-window-manageme and
https://superuser.com/questions/1187532/macos-sierra-full-screen-multi-desktop-with-menu-bar for some working practices on Spaces in general.

Comment: Unfortunately the only thing I could find from those links is confirmation that Apple don't have a solution for working with my setup. It certainly COULD though, since when I have only ONE browser window, cmd+tab takes me to it, whereever it is. 

So my hope is that there is a thirdparty tool that helps me. I am already a paid user of BetterTouchTool to overcome other limitations of Mac. And I do use four finger gesture to switch between spaces. But when I have 4 fullscreen apps and 3 monitors and 2-3 browsers windows, tabbing to application instead of scrolling through spaces is better..

Comment: If you want a software recommendation, this is the wrong stack. See https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ I've given you what is possible natively, in quite some detail.

Comment: ok. thanks Tetsujin

Comment: @Tetsujin spaces is not a fast solution... never will be better than cmd+tab between opened windows, like ANY OTHER OS DO, by default

Comment: @user2342558 - I'm not really sure what you expect by adding your opinion at the bottom of a year-old question. Only myself & the OP will likely ever see it. It doesn't 'fix' or change anything. The system is what it is, no matter what you may wish. Personally, I have never used cmd/tab & can't see the point of it. It's too slow compared to my working method… but I don't spread apps across Spaces. One app, one Space, as it was intended. I don't use fullscreen, because it was badly implemented & never fixed.