# How to navigate / switch apps in MacOS's Mission Control without using the mouse

Tags: mission-control

For maximum keyboard productivity, is there a way to configure Mission Control to allow navigating the apps via arrow key or hjkl?

Comment: As an aside, I have never figured out how using a mouse lowers productivity.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/1187552/347380 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179403/85275

Comment: @john I'll help ya figure it out. #1 some of us have issues using a mouse / touchpad and rely on the accessibility features... talk about a productivity loss. Unfortunately some are forced to use macos because of work or plain ol availability. #2 inherently, making a movement to do something that could be done without moving adds however much time it takes to move. That's a plain ol' observation of reality. #3 Prob the most impactful: measure work done by someone using tools they're happy to use vs fighting against. That gap is very large i imagine.