# How do I align my Mac's virtual desktops according to the order of apps in the dock?

Tags: macos, mac, mission-control

I find myself spending a lot of time switching between virtual desktops/spaces. I think it would be simpler if I had one space per open program, and if my spaces and my dock were in the same order. Reordering the dock should cause reordering of the spaces; and, ideally, vice versa.

Any way to accomplish that?

Comment: It's possible, but you can't make it auto-rearrange; you'll have to set it up manually - see https://superuser.com/a/1187552/347380 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179403/85275 for some working methods.