# How to stop chrome from minimise when opening apps on MacOs

Tags: macos, mac, macos-ventura

i just bought this new Macbook Air M1 2020. It currently use macOS Venture 13.5. I'm new to Mac environment. Before this I'm a windows users. I changed to Mac because i need the Mac kernel & environment

The scenario is when I'm doing something on my screen scrolling chrome, and i want to open calculator, it keeps minimise my chrome and shows calculator on priority.

How can i calculate something, that my reference is in the chrome & the os just minimize it? i want it to be stack for chrome and calculator. Without doing side by side panel.

how can i do that? it is so frustrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running apps in fullscreen, you can't have two apps on one Space simultaneously, unless you side-by-side.

Clicking the green dot, top left, will take an app out of fullscreen & then allow multiple apps to share the same Space.

Comment: Thank you! I guess this is how Mac environment work.

Comment: Yes, fullscreen is a double-edged sword. tbh, it's something I never use, it's too limited. If you want to see how to effectively use Spaces instead, see https://superuser.com/a/1187552/347380 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179403/85275

Comment: That is really good options. Thank you for the link!

Comment: Most welcome - wish you luck in your new experience :))