# How do I cycle through Mac windows for a single application without repeating the most recent windows?

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts, window

I have multiple windows open for TextEdit. Maybe 3 active projects with 3 or 4 windows per project.

I cycle through a few times on a project's windows using <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>. Lets call them windows 1, 2, and 3

I have to move to another project which occupy windows 4, 5, and 6

I open window 4 and then want to cycle through to window 5 but because I cycled through 1, 2, and 3 multiple times, I have to cycle through that same amount of times before getting to 5 or 6. e.g. 1,2,3,2,3,1,2,3,1,3,4,1,3,5,6

Then I need to work on project #3 and get to windows 7, 8, and 9...

<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> does not behave like this. If you cycle you get each application once per entire loop.

How do I get this same behaviour with <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> and only see each application window once per entire loop instead of looping through the entire history?

Comment: I would advise https://github.com/lwouis/alt-tab-macos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any way to change that behaviour, but there's a workaround.

Set up each 'workspace' on a different Space.
That way  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>`</kbd>  will only cycle windows in the current Space.

I know it's not a fix, but it might be a start.

Or alternatively, use tabs. Three windows, three tabs each. Then you can have them all in the same Space, cycle windows with  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>`</kbd>  & tabs with  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Tab ⇥</kbd>

Comment: TIL that TextEdit has tabs! I suppose it is easier to modify my behaviour than to ask Apple to sort it. But only slightly! Why would anybody want the current behaviour? That makes no sense. Thanks for the tip, @Tetsujin.

Comment: FYI this will not work for all applications, if they don't have tabs. Text Edit is just one example. Spaces may work for many people but me and Spaces just don't get along.

Comment: Additionally irritating is that, unlike Safari, you can't use Cmd/num to go straight to a specific tab. …ah, I have to admit to being something of a Spaces fan. I have half a dozen, all neatly arranged by app/subject matter & flit between them all day. It's great so long as you avoid fullscreen, which breaks it. See if https://superuser.com/a/1187552/347380 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179403/85275 could persuade you :)

Comment: I took a look at your tutorial-grade answers and maybe I will take a look down the path of Spaces. Perhaps it is just my lack of knowledge on how to achieve my desired outcome with spaces. Either that or my lack of organisational skills to keep it all under control once I start! Being able to share apps across all desktops was one thing I needed but wasn't aware existed. Or I might have separate spaces per screen as I tend to have all my project specific windows on screen 1. Now the problem is I have too many decisions to make about how to use it, but I think you have a convert!

Comment: Wish you luck! If you have any more questions on using Spaces, throw in a new question & I'll do my best. There are some interoperability tweaks that change with Separate Spaces [which I don't use, I move my two screens as a 'pair'.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible in MacOS 14 Sonoma with:

System Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts... > Keyboard > "Move focus to next window".

The shortcut can be changed from there, to for example Option-Tab, which i prefer.